# Is there an alternative to AutoSizer for 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, automation

Is there an application that sits in your systray and *automatically* moves/resizes windows as they appear (no hotkey press necessary)?

I've been using [AutoSizer](http://www.southbaypc.com/AutoSizer/) for years and sadly it no longer works for me because it doesn't recognize 64-bit windows.

I was so desperate to find a replacement that I installed [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and spent an afternoon writing a script. It worked decently, but because the script was looking for 15 windows, the CPU usage was around 12%. So I threw a Sleep() in my loop and got it down to 3.5%, which was still too high for my taste. The script also left strange artifacts on my desktop after the repositioned window was closed, although that's probably not AutoIt's fault.

Another possible alternative would be [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but looking at the scripting language makes my head hurt. [And it's based on AutoIt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686975), so I don't think the CPU hit will be any better. [Here's a script someone wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893223) that does this for AutoHotkey.

According to [this website](http://alternativeto.net/software/autoit/) and [this article](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-window-manager-resizer-arranger.htm), there are no alternatives that do what AutoSizer does. I've tried them all.

I fully expect the correct answer to be: *There is no alternative*. That being said, which programming language would be good for a novice prgrammer to write a small app that does this? I'd prefer it to be native to the OS, so it can read/write to windows as smoothly as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autosizer works for me in Win7 64bit, but not if set to autostart! Starting the program manually does work, however. Also, if I create a custom task which starts it with a 30 second delay after logging on, it appears to work, too. Maybe it also needs to start with Admin privileges, but I don't know.

Comment: This answer would be helpful if you went to the effort to determine if it doe require administrator privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I am using AutoSizer as well and have not run into the 64-bit window issue, I have found that sometimes ( have to manually specify the sizes as opposed to using 'maximize' mode - can you expand what is the issues you are having?

In my search I have previously found: http://alternativeto.net/software/actual-window-manager/ and I believe you can have it re-position windows on their startup; have not tested myself.

Perhaps you can reach out to the AutoSizer author to see if he will update/open source it/accept a donation to update it. :)

Update: got following response from developer.

```
Yes sir...it's in development still. It had to be rewritten to work with
both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows.

There's no ETA, but it's being worked on.
```